# Run dotnet application on Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: c#, linux, ubuntu, .net-core

I am newbie in net core on Linux and i have a question. I installed .net core 5 and wrote hello world app with name "hello". After, I go to the project bin directory and run my app like:

```
dotnet hello.dll
```

All fine. But i see "hello" (shared library) file in the bin directory too. I can run it in terminal like:

```
./hello
```

All works...
But when i copy files in another location (away from project directory), i can't run my app like: ./hello
I get message "Segmentation fault (core dumped)"  in terminal.

Someone, please, tell me, why after copy files, command "./hello" doesn't work (but dotnet hello.dll works).

Ubuntu 20.04

.NET SDK installed: 5.0.301

.NET runtimes installed: 5.0.7

**UPDATE**
project location:

```
/RiderProjects/RabbitMq-example/RabbitMq-example/bin/Debug/net5.0
```

i copy only net5.0 folder to:

```
/RiderProjects/RMQ/net5.0
```

And I get Segmentation fault.

If i copy full bin folder (like:

```
/RiderProjects/RMQ/bin/Debug/net5.0
```

All fine.

**Steps:**

1. Create folder (e.g. HelloApp)
2. In folder, open terminal and use **dotnet new console**
3. After project creating, use **dotnet publish** in this folder (bin folder will be create after build action)
   (By the current step I have RiderProjects/HelloApp/bin/Debug/net5.0/publish)
4. Copy publish/ folder  (with files) to another location  (in my case, it is
   RiderProjects/publish)
5. **dotnet HelloApp.dll** in publish folder work perfectly, but **./HelloApp** doesn't work

Comment: Are there any other dll files in original folder (or a relative folder)?  Are you copying to same drive?  What command are you using to copy file?  Is the copy dll file size exactly the same as original file?  Segmentation error are usually due to an object being outside the memory assigned to application.

Comment: There is known bug (https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/python-apt/+bug/1907676)  The bug was fixed in 20.04.2.0.

Comment: you ran `./hello` before copy but ran `./hello.sh` after copy, why?

Comment: @LeiYang Sorry, it is misspelling. I fixed it.

Comment: @jdweng I copy that with CTRL+C and paste with CTRL+V via user interface in ubuntu. Yes, copy to same drive and files are original size.

Comment: have you tried [publish](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/dotnet-publish) to generate output folder?

Comment: @LeiYang Yes, same behavior. I add more information about my actions. Sorry that I didn't do this before.

Comment: can you give **simplest** steps to reproduce your issue? for example, use `dotnet new console`, instead of your own real project.

Comment: @LeiYang steps added

Comment: can you update your question, to use `publish` instead?

Comment: i cannot reproduce your problem. i copied files by `cp -R ~/hellonet5/bin/Debug/net5.0 ~/hellonet5/`

Comment: I published my project and copied like you... but command ./HelloApp doesn't work. :(

Comment: maybe it was really due to your ubuntu version(which @jdweng mentioned). it's to costly to upgrade my ubuntu only for reproduce your issue.

Comment: @LeiYang Thanks you for help! If I find a solution, I will post it.

Comment: What version of Net are you using to build?  The Net version to build and the Target version are different. Microsoft has been making fixes build version properly create the right target version.  Also when you change versions of Net you have to make sure you do a clean build so all code gets updated with newer version of Net.  Check you bin folder to make sure all version (Debug/Release) get recompiled.  Often only one gets rebuild and the other fails after changes are made.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you installed the dotnet runtime via snap install you can access it via "sudo dotnet ..." only. I had the same problem in VS Code, it runs the dotnet commands without sudo and I recived the "Segmentation fault (core dumped)" error. I solved by installing the dotnet runtime via apt-get (now is installed in "/usr/bin ..." and works without sudo (see: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/install/linux-ubuntu#2004-))